# Element UI icons wont show up using Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, laravel-mix, element-ui

I made a simple website using Vue and Element UI. I used Laravel Mix to compile my code.

During development, the icons are showing up but when I run "npm run prod" and upload it to Github Pages they wont show up.

This is my webpack.mix.js

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('src/js/app.js', 'public/')
.sass('src/styles/app.scss', 'public/')
.babelConfig({})
.disableNotifications();
```

I am using on demand components and followed this [doc](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart#on-demand) so my root vue file looks like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from './vuex'
import router from './vue-router'
import Element from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import lang from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/es'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale'

locale.use(lang)

Vue.use(Loading.directive);
Vue.component(Select.name, Select)
Vue.component(Option.name, Option)
Vue.component(Input.name, Input)
Vue.component(Icon.name, Icon)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
});
```

Following the same doc, I added a .babelrc file on my root directory but I didn't managed to get it working with the preset `es2015` so I used `@babel/preset-env` instead. I dont actually know how to properly use Babel so the whole error might be over here but idk.

```json
{
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }]],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "component",
        {
          "libraryName": "element-ui",
          "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I noticed something weird, when I run npm run prod, the output shows something like this:
[image]

The fonts folder and the needed fonts are being copied to my root directory, so when its on Github it makes a request to the root domain, the root folder, the right url should be over (I guess?) `/h3lltronik.github.io/my-site/` but it is on `/h3lltronik.github.io/`.

[image]

Just in case is needed, Im using the icons like this:

```html
<el-input v-model="search" prefix-icon="el-icon-search" class="filter_input element-input bordered" @input="onChangeSearch"
        placeholder="Search for a country..."></el-input>
```

And this is my index.html

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>H3lltronik</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" :class="modeClass">
        <transition name="el-fade-in">
            <router-view class="content-body"></router-view>
        </transition>
    </div>

    <script src="./public/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```